Implementation of the diversity strategy of MSCPSO
The Multi-Swarm Self-Adaptive and Cooperative Particle Swarm Optimization algorithm (MSCPSO) from this paper mentions a diversity strategy to enable better exploration capabilities over the standard PSO algorithm.
How is it implemented? Example value of the parameters? Duration of the exploration?
From my understanding, when the pbest of each sub-swarn as not improved over n iterations, thus computing $||pbest_{alltime}-pbest_{current}||_1 < \epsilon$, $g_{best}$ is replaced by its opposite for every particles.
